# MVC3 ViewModel in form without helpers has only null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view tied to a strongly typed ViewModel but I'm **not** using the MVC3 HTML helpers, just normal HTML `input` tags.  However, this seems to not be passing the values correctly to the action method as the ViewModel is entirely null.

ViewModel:

```
class QuoteSearch {
    public long? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model QuoteSearch

<form action="/quotes/search" method="POST">
    <p>Customer ID: <input id="CustomerIdField" name="CustomerId" type="text" /></p>
    <p>Customer First Name: <input id="CustomerFirstNameField" name="CustomerFirstName" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Customer Last Name: <input id="CustomerLastNameField" name="CustomerLastName" type="text"/></p>
    <p><button id="SearchButton" type="submit">Search</button></p>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(QuoteSearch search) { 
     // checking if fields are set here.
 }
```

I seem to remember there being a way to NOT have to use the Html helpers but still use a strongly-typed model (as opposed to a `FormCollection`); I thought it involved setting the name attribute to be the exact name of the property on the model, but I seem to have been mistaken.

Comment: QuoteId input is a typo? the viewmodel contains a CustomerId property

Comment: Strange... your code should work (expect that you have `QuoteId` but on your model `CustomerId `). Because the Html helpers basically just renders the input elements with the `name` as the propertyname.

Comment: Try to change this `name="QuoteId"` for `name="CustomerId"`

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo.  I had it QuoteId at first and changed it later, forgot to update post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your names don't all align (as suggested in the comments) but for the fields that do line up, the model is correctly populated when I execute the above code (names are there, CustomerId is null).

Are you setting a breakpoint, and do you know that the code is being hit?

Please also confirm that your controller is called Quotes. Even if it is, you will be better to use:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("search", "quotes")" method="POST">
```

...so that routing works even if you add areas etc.  The Url helper will work out the correct path for the request based on your routing rules.

Finally, if you're not hitting that execution point with a breakpoint set, be sure to use F12/dev tools to monitor your network requests and make sure that the correct address is being called.  The above snippet should also help resolve that.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: Yeah, I was debugging it and it was hitting the Search method, but the `QuoteSearch` model had all null values.  I'm using MVC3 as part of an Asp.Net Web Site project though, so maybe something isn't wired up correctly?

Comment: I wonder if that's it; I used a blank MVC3 project and that same code populates it, but in the hybrid Web Site/MVC project everything is null.

Comment: Okay...my gut is that definitely is related, especially if you've got bits at different versions and the versions of the Asp.Net features (like routing, model binding, etc) aren't playing nicely. I think this is where you should spend your time, especially if a wrote Mvc project is working for you.  Try to either port to a straight-MVC project (if you can) or implement a solution that gets your model binding working in your context. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try name="[ViewModel].[FieldName]" and id="[ViewModel]_[FieldName]"

These are what values I have in the input tags when using the HTML helpers.

So for you it would be:

```
<input type="text" name="QuoteSearch.CustomerId" id="QuoteSearch_CustomerId" />
```

etc..